# Changing Application Name in Windows Installer

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, windows-installer, application-name

I have created a setup project for a Windows Application developed using Visual Stduio 2008(C#).

In the portion of installation screen where it says, **this installer will guide you through the steps required to install *ABC* on your computer**

I want this changed to **this installer will guide you through the steps required to install *XYZ* on your computer**

How can I change the word ABC to XYZ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the name that appears on Welcome Screen, you would need to edit as follow.

Right click on Installer Project name > View > User Interface.

From there, edit the properties of Welcome under Start.

Answer (score 20):

**Follow these steps to change your application's name:**

1. Ensure that your setup project is open in Visual Studio.
2. Click on the project's root-level icon in the Solution Explorer.
3. In the Properties Window, change the [`ProductName` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y066fs8a.aspx) to "XYZ" or whatever you want the installer to display as your application's name.

   [image]
4. Rebuild the setup project.

Now, if your right-click on the project icon in the Solution Explorer and click "Install", the setup program will start and you can verify that the application name that it displays is correct.

**It's also worth investigating the other [deployment properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/seykw6dt.aspx) that are available for setup projects to make sure that these are set appropriately for your application.**

Comment: Thanks for you comments. If I double clock on the SetupProject name, I do not see the screen you mentioned. Instead, The Project simply expands in name. Is something missing?

Comment: @Gunner: Just single-click on the SetupProject name, and then look at your Properties Window. All you want to do is highlight your setup project so that you can edit it's properties in the Properties Window.

Comment: Thanks again for you reply. But for some reason, I don't see what you mentioned. Instead, I get something else which says about Build and configuration manager.

Comment: Yeah, because you're right-clicking and selecting "Properties". The "Properties" option in the context menu is *not the same thing* as the "Properties Window". I don't really know how else to explain it. Look at the screenshot above: the "Properties Window" is a separate, floating toolbox window, *not a dialog box*. Try clicking ONCE on the project and then pressing F4. That should bring your "Properties Window" to the front.

Comment: I found what you are trying to show, but what I wanted to change is not in the property. It's in the User Interface section.